# Eaton UPS detection problem: Eaton Ellipse ECO 800 on Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: usb, xubuntu, ups, nut

I have '[Eaton Ellipse ECO 800](http://powerquality.eaton.com/Products-services/Backup-Power-UPS/Ellipse-ECO.aspx?cx=72)' UPS on Xubuntu 14.04. Manufacturer claims Linux support in the UPS' specification. The same does the NUT' '[Hardware compatibility list](http://networkupstools.org/stable-hcl.html)'.

The problem is that kernel (or udev) doesn't "feel" the UPS is *plugged* in USB socket (no matter USB2 or USB3).

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp.
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Nevertheless a Flash Drive is detected normally plugged in the same socket.

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp.
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0930:6545 Toshiba Corp. Kingston DataTraveler 102/2.0 / HEMA Flash Drive 2 GB / PNY Attache 4GB Stick
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

How to solve the problem? Do anybody have suggestion?

Thanks.